# R and nls with functions error - 'must have same number of rows'

Tags: r, nls

I am wanting to find optimum parameters for a function that determines survival from hazard rates (force of mortality).

```
eh <- function(kappa,lambda,time,delay){
  FoM <- -log(1-(1-exp(-kappa*(time+delay)))*(exp(-lambda*time)))  
  return(FoM)  
}

survival <- function(k, l, t, d){
  theSurvs <- array(1, c(1, length(t)))
  S = array(1)
  Qs <- array(0)
  for(j in 1:length(t)){
    S[1] = 1
    for(i in 1:(t[j]+1)){
      theEHs <- eh(k, l, i-1, d)
      theQs <- hazards2Qs(theEHs)
      S[i+1] <- S[i]-S[i]*theQs
    }
    theSurvs[j] <- S[i]
  }
  return(theSurvs)
}

hazards2Qs <- function(hazards){
  Qs<- 1-exp(-hazards)
  return(Qs)
}

timeX = 0  # time cycles of arbitrary length
kappaX = 0.001
lambdaX = 0.05
delayX = 50

theYears <- floor(runif(20)*100)
theYears

EHs <- eh(kappaX, lambdaX, theYears, delayX)


theS <- survival(kappaX, lambdaX, theYears, delayX)
theS

theData <- data.frame(theYears, t(theS))
theData
survival(kappaX, lambdaX, theYears, delayX)

mod <- nls(~ survival(kappa, lambda, theYears, delay), start=list(lambda=0.0015, kappa=0.0013, delay=48), data=theData, trace=1)
```

When I run it I get this error:

```
3.647752 :   0.0015  0.0013 48.0000
Error in qr.qty(QR, resid) : 
  'qr' and 'y' must have the same number of rows
```

traceback():

```
4: stop("'qr' and 'y' must have the same number of rows")
3: qr.qty(QR, resid)
2: (function () 
   {
       if (npar == 0) 
           return(0)
       rr <- qr.qty(QR, resid)
       sqrt(sum(rr[1L:npar]^2)/sum(rr[-(1L:npar)]^2))
   })()

> dim(theS)
[1]  1 20
> dim(theYears)
NULL
> dim(theData)
[1] 20  2
> typeof(theData)
[1] "list"
> typeof(theS)
[1] "double"
> typeof(theYears)
[1] "double"
```

I have been slogging for a day and not got to the bottom of this. Any ideas?

Comment: Without sample data this error isn't [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). It it a lot easier to get help if you have a complete running example that returns the same error. See the link for suggestions for including a sample data set.

Comment: Sorry, I failed to copy one of the functions over correctly. Now put back in and it should run to reproduce the error mentioned.

Comment: The sample data is generated by the code as dummy data that goes into the data frame 'theData'.

Comment: R version 3.1.0, run in Ubuntu 12.04 and using RStudio. NO packages added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending a long time trying to figure out what was going on myself, I think the problem is how you're shaping your `survival` function results. I'm not sure why you're trying to return an array, but you should be returning a vector here. So just change the first line to

```
#OLD: theSurvs <- array(1, c(1, length(t)))
theSurvs <- rep.int(1, length(t)
```

which means you'll also have to change

```
#OLD: theData <- data.frame(theYears, t(theS))
theData <- data.frame(theYears, theS)
```

By returning a shaped object like that, it was interfering with the gradient calculation which uses `qr()`. Try to stay away from single dimension arrays when possible and just use simple vectors.

Now, that being said, fixing that problem seems to lead to another one. It seems that when it's trying to take the numerical derivative, it's running into `NaN/Inf` values. You can add this code above your `return(theSurvs)` line to see the parameters that are called when this happens

```
if(any(!is.finite(theSurvs))) {
    dput(c(k,l,d))
    dput(t)
    print(theSurvs)     
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks. I knew it would be something simple and dumb.